# Predicting cognitive decline on RBANS test

Tags: test, neuropsychology

The **RBANS (Repeatable Battery for the Assessment of Neuropsychological Status (RBANS))** is used to evaluate cognitive function in patients with cognitive impairment, stroke or traumatic brain injury. The score is composed of five domains scores (Immediate Memory, Visuospatial/ Constructional, Language and Delayed Memory) and a total score.

I am now seeing a patient in a follow-consultation and I am trying to figure out whether the change in his RBANS score after 1 year is significant or not. **There is a regression formula provided in this paper (1) which allows to calculate the predicted RBANS score at a follow up time.** A deviation from this score allows to identify a significant change. Here a capture of the table:

[image]

*Education in years is coded as* 11 years or less = 1, 12 years = 2, 13–15 years = 3, 16 years or more = 4

In the same paper, the authors provide an example (Male, 75 years, 10 years education, 1 year follow-up):
[image]

**My question**: Before applying this equation to my patient, I wanted to reproduce the results from their example in Table 5. However, I am not coming to the same results and I think this might be due to an issue with the linear regression equation formula I derived from Table 2. I would be very thankful if someone could provide me with a hint here? I understand the question might be very basic.

Here is the formula I derived from Table 2:
Linear regression (for Total Scale for example):

```
Predicted RBANS Time 2 = 37.65 (Constant) + 0.75*Time 1 Index Score - 0.23*Age in years + 1.47*education in years + 7.81 (Standard Error of the Estimate)
```

Using data from example in Table 5:

```
37.65+0.75*91-0.23*76+1.47*1+7.81=97.7 > which is wrong.
```

Thank you very much for your consideration.

*References:
(1) Duff K, Schoenberg MR, Patton D, Mold J, Scott JG, Adams RL. Predicting change with the RBANS in a community dwelling elderly sample. J Int Neuropsychol Soc. 2004;10(6):828-834. doi:10.1017/s1355617704106048*